# Flash syntax problem

Tags: flash, syntax

Quick question.

Trying to get error clip to play if email is not good, trying

```
if (trace(emailExpression.test(email.text))) 
{
    error_email.play();
}
```

but it's playing even if email is right. any thoughts? I think its something with syntax!

Comment: Why are you calling `trace()` in your if statement?

Comment: mainly because i never done AS, so just guessing the way :) do I have to create a function then?

Comment: just remove the trace... emailExpression is an object that has the method test which expects a String which in your case is the email.text value

Answer (score 1):

`trace()` returns `void` whereas for an `if()` statement to function as expected you want to parse a value that equates either to `true` of `false`.

Maybe try ditching the `trace()` and see if that works - I'm not sure what `test()` does so I can't be certain.

```
if(emailExpression.test(email.text)) 
{
    error_email.play();
}
```

Comment: if you want to trace the output of `emailExpression.test` for debugging purposes, do it separately.